# Multiple upload, only the last file is uploaded

Tags: php, upload

I am currently working on a website project, and need to have more than one image uploaded in the same form.

When the form is submitted, only the last picture is uploaded, and I can't figure out why. I've been looking on an answer on Google, this website and many others, but I couldn't find anyone with exactly the same problem to find a solution.

I have tested this basic code both with WAMP and online, and the problem remains the same...

Here's the form :

```
<form action="index.php?action=add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file1"/><br/>
<input type="file" name="file2"/><br/>
<input type="file" name="file3"/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" value="ok"/>
```

And here is the code I use for the upload :

```
function move_avatar($avatar)
{
    $extension_upload = strtolower(substr(  strrchr($avatar['name'], '.')  ,1));
    $name = time();
    $nomavatar = str_replace(' ','',$name).".".$extension_upload;
    $name = "images/".str_replace(' ','',$name).".".$extension_upload;
    move_uploaded_file($avatar['tmp_name'],$name);
    return $nomavatar;
}
if(!empty($_POST['add'])){
    for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
        if(!empty($_FILES['file'.$i]['size'])){
            $extensions_valides = array( 'jpg' , 'jpeg' , 'gif' , 'png', 'bmp' );           
            $extension_upload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['file'.$i]['name'], '.')  ,1));
            if(in_array($extension_upload,$extensions_valides))     
            $img =(!empty($_FILES['file'.$i]['size']))?move_avatar($_FILES['file'.$i]):'';
            else $img = 'defaultImg.png';
        }else $img = 'defaultImg.png';
    }
    print_r($_POST);
}else include('test.php');
```

Any ideas ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's Caroline from Facebook !

Even if you read my answer on Facebook, I post this answer to indicate that this problem is solved.

After testing your script, I found what's wrong.
The problem is located in your function, where you declare the $name variable :

```
$name = time();
```

When you upload several pics at the same time, they all have the same timestamp and thus, the same name !  That's why only the last pic is sent !

To fix this, I added an argument in your function in order to add a digit that will make the filenames different from each other :

```
function move_avatar($avatar,$number)
```

Then I added this new variable to the first $name variable :

```
    $name = time().$number;
```

And finally, I use the $i variable when the function is used :

```
                $img =(!empty($_FILES['file'.$i]['size']))?move_avatar($_FILES['file'.$i],$i):'';
```

With these modifications, all images uploaded have now a distinct name, the last digit being different.