# multiple file option giving only one row

Tags: php

i am using php multipe file upload , when i try to submit it only returns the last selected file.
below is my code in html part

```
<input type="file" id="files" multiple name="abcdeffiles[]"  />
```

and in php i use

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES);
```

and the result i get only last selected file
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

```
[abcdeffiles] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 808b182dfc544ec4faee769dae082072.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => image/jpeg
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => H:\xampp\tmp\php2057.tmp
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 72512
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: `808b182dfc544ec4faee769dae082072.jpg` is a very unique file name. Is it possible you are changing the file name on php, and it is overwriting it? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167349/689579

Comment: @Sean yes i saved my image with this file name, not adding any script to change the file name, but i am not able to get all the files , only the last file that i select from input type file is seen when i post it on server.

Comment: So you select one file from one folder then again you click browse select another file and so on... but on server you get only the last file ..right?

Comment: @Viney Yes exactly.

Comment: Well for that you must use multiple file controls because that's how they behave they forget the previous items when you use them next time.See this exactly identical your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602704/how-prevent-files-loss-data/49608387